# Scrapy Mysql pipeline if table NO AUTO_INCREMENT and NO UNIQUE - how to assign category_id?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, scrapy, mysql-python

Scrapy Mysql pipeline if table NO AUTO_INCREMENT and NO UNIQUE - how to assign category_id in category_description table and then assign this category_id to related table category? 
Scraped item = item category name

Example table structure for table `category_description`

```
CREATE TABLE `category_description` 
(`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,          # NO AUTO_INCREMENT   
`language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,            # NOT UNIQUE  
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`language_id`),  
KEY `name` (`name`)) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Example table structure for related table `category`

```
CREATE TABLE `category` 
(  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),  
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

```
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):    
    def __init__(self):        
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='user', passwd='pass', db='test', host='localhost', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)        
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()         
        try:            
            self.cursor.execute("select * from it_category_description where name = %s",(item['category']))            
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()            
        if result:               
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)            
        else:                
            self.cursor.execute("""ALTER TABLE it_category_description CHANGE category_id category_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT""")                
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO it_category_description (name) VALUES (%s)""", (item['category']))                
            self.conn.commit()            
        category_id = self.cursor.lastrowid            
        print '***********', self.cursor.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Mysql Pipeline for table without AUTO_INCREMENT and without UNIQUE . Anybody know more elegant solution?

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    tx.execute("""SELECT MAX(category_id) as xx FROM category_description""")
    max = tx.fetchall()[0]['xx'] or 0
    tx.execute("""INSERT INTO category_description (category_id, name, language_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(max+1 , item['category'][0], 1))
    category_id = tx.lastrowid
```